# Is there a way to avoid the Cast<T>() if I already have the correct type in the following C# scenario?

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class ItemStore {
    private Dictionary<Type, List<object>> _items = new Dictionary<Type, List<object>>();

    public void AddItem(object item) {
        var type = item.GetType();
        if (!_items.ContainsKey(type)) {
            _items[type] = new List<object>();
        }
        _items[type].Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>() {
        if(!_items.ContainsKey(typeof(T))) {
            return new List<T>();
        }
        return _items[typeof(T)].Cast<T>();
    }
}
```

(The real scenario is more complex, and it is a library used in multiple Projects knowing nothing about the concrete types.... )

The `Cast<T>()` in `GetItems()` is consuming quite some time. So I would prefere to avoid it. Is there any way to avoid it in C# - because actually the list already contains the correct types?

Comment: Cast the list object itself? Might need a dynamic `CreateInstance`

Comment: The list might contain the correct type but the list is still a `List<object>`, so no, the only option is casting each and every element; `Cast<T>()`

Comment: No, you cannot avoid `.Cast<T>()` (or `.OfType<T>()`). You are given a List<object> from the dictionary, but want to return it as an IEnumerable<T>, so...

Comment: The list already contains the correct types, but the list is actually typed as `List<object>`. No way to get the underlying objects out without a cast of each one. Perhaps if you had typed internally as `IList` it might be possible to cast back to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Here is an interesting read on the topic by [Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/10/08/mapping-from-a-type-to-an-instance-of-that-type/). The comments talk about the cost of casting vs. the overhead of maintaining an internal structure designed to avoid the casting.

Comment: Is there a reason AddItem is not generic? If you can modify that signature, things would be much simpler.

Comment: Have you looked at [`KeyedByTypeCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyedbytypecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.1)?

Comment: I do wonder how you've established that this casting, specifically, is what's consuming time in a measurable way. I could see *inconvenient*, but I have a harder time seeing *time-consuming*. I'd expect that what you *do* with the enumerable afterwards is what takes more time. (It's important to establish what actually takes time, because various workarounds may still involve casting and/or boxing in ways that don't effectively gain you anything overall.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert - the lib I'm talking about is used in an app which is doing a lot of arithmetics and needs to get a lot of time child collections all over the place - and if measured with a tool like dotTrace I saw that the code spends about half of the time in the GetItems function and there in the Cast...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use IList instead of List(T)
- Make AddItem() method generic

  ```
  public class ItemStore
  {
    private Dictionary<Type, IList> _items = new Dictionary<Type, IList>();

    public void AddItem<T>(T item)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!_items.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            _items[type] = new List<T>();
        }
        _items[type].Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>()
    {
        if (!_items.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return new List<T>();
        }
        return (List<T>)_items[typeof(T)];
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 7):

You need to modify the internal structure of this class a bit to not use generics in the items lookup because we need to underlying type of the stored list to be the correct type. This requires a little reflection when creating the list. We can also make AddItem and GetItems a little more efficient by avoiding extra lookups:

```
public class ItemStore {
    private Dictionary<Type, IList> _items = new Dictionary<Type, IList>();

    public void AddItem(object item) {
        var type = item.GetType();
        IList list;
        if (!_items.TryGetValue(type, out list)) {
            var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
            list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
            _items[type] = list;
        }

        list.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>() {
        IList list;
        if(!_items.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list)) {
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        } else {
            return (IEnumerable<T>)list;
        }
    }
}
```

If you can modify the signature of AddItem this could be even simpler (no reflection), but given you've said this is an over simplification, I will leave the public API unchanged.

Comment: This technically avoids the cast when retrieving the item, but a cast is still happening when calling `list.Add(item)`, by virtue of how `List<T>` necessarily implements `IList.Add`. It's all about when you prefer to cast, I suppose...

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sure but it's already been boxed by the caller so we aren't doing anything extra in here. If we can make AddItem generic, then that boxing can be avoided. There could be reasons AddItem is not generic. For example if AddItem is used by the caller in some reflection scenario anyway calling a generic method will be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @mikez Actually my AddItem function in the real lib is already generic. But I will definitely remember your way to create a generic type like this!

Answer (score 2):

You could make your method AddItem generic, which would allow you to store `List<T>` instances in your dictionary (whose generic *TValue* parameter should be `IList` in this case).

```
public class ItemStore
{
    private Dictionary<Type, IList> _items = new Dictionary<Type, IList>();

    public void AddItem<T>(T item)
    {
        IList objList;
        if (!_items.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out objList))
        {
            objList = new List<T>();
            _items[typeof(T)] = objList;
        }
        objList.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>()
    {
        IList objList;
        return
            (_items.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out objList)) ? (List<T>)objList
            : new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Same as the answer above, but I can not mark two ansers as answer. I like the idea of TryGetValue()!

Comment: Don't worry about marking or not marking my answer. For all practical purposes, Oxald's and my answer are so similar it doesn't matter which one you pick...